# Two application servers on one web server?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, nginx

I have a Rails app which provides service through Nginx server(with thin). Now I want to build another app in Node.js on the same machine.

My question is, can I have Nginx redirect users' reqeusts? e.g. when a user access 'foo.mydomain.com' it will be processed by Rails app, and when she visit 'bar.mydomain.com' it can be processed by Node app.

(I'm not sure whether it's related to the type of apps, i.e. Rails, Nodejs, etc)

Comment: it is a serverfault.com question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up two serverblocks in your nginx config; One listening for bar.mydomain.com and the other one for foo.mydomain.com and then use the [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) module in nginx to pass forward the requests to your Node or Rails app.